# Access Denied even if permission is given

Tags: users

I have this module, as admin users I can access this module normally. But when I add permission to other roles (and it saved), other users who have the permimssion couldn't access it. Please help me.

This is the code.

```
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'tb') .'/tb.menu.inc');
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'tb') .'/tb.inc');

function tb_perm() {
  global $user;
  return array('trial_balance');
}

function tb_menu() {
  global $user;
  $items = array();

  $items['akuntansi/tb'] = array(
    'title' => 'Trial Balance',
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'tb_neracapage',
    'file' => 'tb.inc',
    'access arguments' => array('akuntansi'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    //'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['akuntansi/tb/pdf'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'tb_neracapage_pdf',
    'file' => 'tb.inc',
    'access arguments' => array('akuntansi'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
$items['akuntansi/tb/xls'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'tb_neracapage_xls',
    'file' => 'tb.inc',
    'access arguments' => array('akuntansi'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `hook_perm()` (which is not valid for Drupal 7), only defines the *trial_balance* permission, not the *akuntansi* permission your code is trying to use.
The fact the user #1 has the permission to see those pages is just because the user #1 by-passes all the permissions; in fact, `user_access()` returns `TRUE` for that user.

```
  // User #1 has all privileges:
  if ($account->uid == 1) {
    return TRUE;
  }
```

To make it clear, without explicitly setting an access callback, the access arguments are expected to be an array with the user permission string, which in your case would be *trial_balance*.

If the module is for Drupal 7, then `hook_perm()` is not even used; instead, Drupal 7 uses [`hook_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7), which is not a simple renaming of the previous hook. It is expected to return a differently structured array; using the same array as Drupal 6, will cause it to not properly work.